# Changing text of an autogenerated select column of a gridview in asp.net - How?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, gridview

I would like to change the text of the autogenerated `"select"` column in an ASP.NET `GridView` control. The text needs to be changed to the value of a `DataField`.

I suspect that there is a very logical way to do this but I am missing it.
I am able to add controls and data via the pre-render event but is there an easier better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the TemplateField and place into it buttons or linkbuttons with appropriate CommandName property: [ButtonField.CommandName Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.buttonfield.commandname.aspx)
You may set this button text using DataBinder.Eval method.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way I found to do this is after the calling DataBind() just before the gridview control is displayed.

```
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gvAgreementList.Rows)
        {
            LinkButton lb = (LinkButton) row.Cells[0].Controls[0];
            lb.Text = "Edit";
        }
```

Comment: thank you dear BMASolutions, i use this (2 line into loop) in  my solution in event GridView_RowDataBound.

Comment: This is the most consistent way to do this when using a GridView CommandField. This let's you easily change the CommandField EditText for each row.

    gvwUnapprovedCommissions.DataSource = dsPending;
    gvwUnapprovedCommissions.DataBind();
    if (GetCurrentUserRole().ToString() != "Admin")
    {
             // Change the command button text to View for all except Admin.
             foreach (GridViewRow row in gvwUnapprovedCommissions.Rows)
         {
              LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)row.Cells[0].Controls[0];
              lb.Text = "View";
         }
     }

Answer (score 7):

after `<column>` write this:

```
<asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" SelectText="Save" />
```

and remove `AutoGenerateSelectButton="True"` from `Gridview` attribute.

Answer (score 3):

First remove auto generated select then go to `GridView` tasks.. top right Button of `GridView` and then click on `commandfields` -> `Select` then edit `SelectText`.

(Edited answer of ShaileshK with some changes)

Answer (score 2):

Go to GridVIew tasks.. top right Button of GridView and then click on edit columns
In selected fields section Click on select field. change the value of select text.
done.