# select button on gridview - asp.net

Tags: asp.net

in asp.net, when you have an autogenreated select button on a gridview, is it possible to change the text of it from 'select' to something else of your choosing? If so can anyone point me to an example?

thanks again

Comment: Could you provide the code for your grid?

Comment: Hi  Ive included it in an answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this similar question:

[Changing text of an autogenerated select column of a gridview in asp.net - How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232045/changing-text-of-an-autogenerated-select-column-of-a-gridview-in-asp-net-how)

Example:

```
<asp:buttonfield buttontype="Button" 
                 commandname="Select"
                 headertext="Select Customer" 
                 text="SelectText"/>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvSearch" runat="server" Visible="False" 
                OnPageIndexChanging="Grid_Changing" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" 
                AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" CellPadding="4" Font-Names="Arial" 
                Font-Size="XX-Small" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
                onselectedindexchanged="gvSearch_SelectedIndexChanged" PageSize="100">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
            </asp:GridView>
```